# R: How do I use a for loop to mutate & group_by multiple data frames

Tags: r

I'm pretty familiar to R, but a complete novice when it comes to for loops.

Basically I have roughly 50 million observations of Current Population Survey data from 1977-2015, I'm looking to:

A). Subset all the data by year

B). mutate all the subsetted dfs with multiple new variables

C). group_by State ID, and summarise the mean of several variables for that state in that particular year

D). put my new summarised data all back together

I have no trouble doing this manually, but it's extremely repetitive and I'd love to make my code more efficient. Here's an example of how I can achieve it manually:

```
FinalCPS<- load.csv("CPS")

CPS1977 <- FinalCPS %>% filter(YEAR==1977)

CPS1977 <- CPS1977 %>% mutate(newvar = ..)

CPS1977 <- CPS1977 %>% group_by(STATEID) %>%  summarise(mean(var1),mean(var1))
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: You should also group by `Year` instead of filtering them one by one. `CPS1977 %>% group_by(STATEID, YEAR) %>% summarise(mn = mean(var1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add more variable in group_by,for loop not required if you have large data set.
you can try something like that for cumulative sum.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.table(df)
df[, Newvar1:= cumsum(var1), by = c("STATEID","YEAR")]
```

which makes more efficient way of dealing with large data set.

Answer (score 0):

This may look a bit convoluted, piecing together several SO posts, so likely not the most efficient way to go, but one approach to downloading multiple census files and reading them into a table:

```
y<-1985
f<-"~/data/"
if (!dir.exists(f)) {dir.create(f)}
setwd(f)
while (y < 2016)  {
      y=y+1
      ty=substr(y,3,4)
      url<-paste0("https://www2.census.gov/programs-surveys/cbp/datasets/",y,"/cbp",ty,"st.zip")
      p<-basename(url)
      if (!file.exists(p)) {download.file(url = url,
                                          destfile = p,mode="wb")}
      library(plyr)
      # get all the zip files
      zipF <- list.files(path = f, pattern = "*.zip", full.names = TRUE)

      # unzip all your files
      ldply(.data = zipF, .fun = unzip, exdir = f)

      # clean up
      delfiles <- dir(path=f ,pattern=".zip")
      file.remove(file.path(f, delfiles))
}

list_of_files <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE,
                            pattern = "\\.txt$", 
                            full.names = TRUE)
library(data.table)

# Read all the files and create a FileName column to store filenames
DT <- rbindlist(sapply(list_of_files, fread, simplify = FALSE),
                use.names = TRUE, idcol = "FileName")
```

You'll have to make the final push to get the group means that you want.